# jmap -histo:live output is empty

Tags: java, jvm, histogram, heap-memory, jmap

Sometimes when I execute a command:
**"$JAVA_HOME/bin/jmap -histo:live " + pid + " > " + fileName**
I get an empty(blank) file.

Why this may happen?

***P.S. This is using in autotest (test on memory leaks).***
With option -F (forced) I get histogram, but it includes non-live objects.

Thx, for any help.